# Hidding (Blank) Data in PivotGrid

Tags: telerik

#### 1/. My DataBase SquetchUp , and Request:

I have those 2 table :

```
 Table_EC:                                   Table_P:
+------+---------+------------------+       +---------+--------+--------+
| Name | IdValue | ManyOtherInfo... |       | IdValue | Value1 | Value4 |
+-----------------------------------+       +---------------------------+
| STR  |  INT    |     ManyTYPE     |       |  Int    |  Label | OrderBy|
+------+---------+------------------+       +---------+--------+--------+
```

In order to diplay in a cross table  I do this request:

```sql
SELECT  NAME , VALUE1
FROM    Table_EC 
        RIGHT JOIN Table_P
            ON Table_EC.VALUE1= Table_P.VALUE1 
ORDER BY PAR_VALEUR4
```

#### 2/. Telerik MarkUp

My `RadPivotGrid` declaration:

```html
<telerik:RadPivotGrid ID="RadPivotGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RPG_RECAP_NeedDataSource" >
    <TotalsSettings RowGrandTotalsPosition="None" RowsSubTotalsPosition="None" />
    <Fields>
        <telerik:PivotGridAggregateField GrandTotalAggregateFormatString="" CalculationExpression="" 
            UniqueName="Statut" DataField="Value1" Aggregate="Count"  >
            <TotalFormat Level="0" Axis="Columns" TotalFunction="NoCalculation" SortOrder="Ascending"></TotalFormat>                
        </telerik:PivotGridAggregateField>                        
        <telerik:PivotGridRowField UniqueName="RowCLI" DataField="Name" />
        <telerik:PivotGridColumnField UniqueName="ColumnStatut" DataField="Value1" />      
    </Fields>
</telerik:RadPivotGrid>
```

#### 3/. Current Result:

[image: Result]
The expected result are the same but with out the (Blank) Row

**How do i achieve this ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now my answer is : **You can't**

What i have done to "fix the issue":
( By fix I mean make the information more relevant for the Customer)
Count on a null value in the AggregateField Here ValueID.
Not on Value1 will make blank row display 0 . 
Dont forget to set `IgnoreNullValues="true"` and `ShowGroupsWhenNoData="false"`.